# PHP AJAX POST getting wrong data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX request to a PHP but it is not returning the correct data.

My AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({     
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://www.boomlings.com/database/getGJUserInfo20.php',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    dataType: "text",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {
            gameVersion: 20,
            binaryVersion: 29,
            str: 'Nexrem',
            page: 0,
            total: 0,
            secret: 'Wmfd2893gb7'
    },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log('success:')
        console.log(response)
    },
    error: function(erresponse){
        console.log('error:')
        console.log(erresponse)
    }
});
```

this always returns `-1` instead of a data string.

I captured the packets of my AJAX request and a request that works (by official client)

[image]

mine on the left and official on the right.

The official one seems to receive the data string but mine doesn't. I am unsure of what I might be doing wrong.

I can also provide the PHP I'm communicating with but note that I cannot and will not modify it. https://github.com/Cvolton/GMDprivateServer/blob/master/getGJUserInfo20.php

Comment: returns -1 where? in `console.log(response)`? Where do you send `"targetAccountID"` that is used in that linked php?

Comment: @Jeff yes in the console log. No, str is the targetAccountID. I'm mostly being referenced by a python script that does this and works. http://pastebin.com/Hauy0uJu

Comment: could it then be that the error is the database? maybe connection.php is returning -1 and stopping the script already?

Comment: @Jeff unlikely. The python script I linked above is doing the same thing but getting a correct response.

Comment: can you then post the `working`phyton script? (You've linked the php)

Comment: @jeff http://pastebin.com/Hauy0uJu

Comment: sure your's is the left response? The utf-8 is in the pyton explicitly, not in your js. But to be honest, I'm only guessing now....

Comment: @jeff yes the left one is mine. Ajax seems to automatically do UTF8 but it doesn't really matter since both are URL encoded and URL's are UTF8 by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Human error. Link was wrong. I used `GetUserInfo20.php` instead of `GetUsers.php`.